# How do I make material design components such as button ripples and shadows compliant with AAA accessibility?

Tags: material-design, accessibility

I'm planning on my website having material-inspired design without using a framework. How can I use such iconic material components such as the button ripple and elevation without sacrificing AAA color contrast?

### Shadow

I want to use the `.gmd-2` material shadow from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/wisnust10/pen/NNpjPE). It uses two shadows, one with the color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), and the other with the color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), both of which fail AA with a white background, according to https://contrast-ratio.com.

### Ripple

I want to use [the Waves light ripple](https://github.com/fians/Waves/blob/v0.7.6/src/scss/waves.scss#L77), which is the ripple color rgba(255,255,255,0.4), which doesn't pass AAA even in black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should measure color contrast of text but not shadows of blocks.

> Ensure all text elements have sufficient color contrast between the text in the foreground and background color behind it.

https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/color-contrast?application=AxeChrome

Use right accessibility testing tools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd

Comment: What about other foreground elements like images?

Comment: If image contains text, it shoud be checked too